# Finder Global Grid Setting

Tags: finder

I'm running the latest version of mavericks and was just wondering if there is a way to set a grid sizes globally so that spaces between folder and files is the same throughout finder?

At the moment if I navigate through folders, the grid sizes are different in each folder .

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you need to set up a folder and then select the "Use as Defaults" button located at the bottom of the View Options window.

[image]

Once that is set, any new folder will adopt those settings. Note that any current folder view that has already been adjusted will ignore the setting and need to be re-adjusted. This is due to Finder saving view options instantly and not having the "Use as Defaults" option overriding them.